# Service PHP in Rails

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a small PHP service that is being called in a JavaScript file by AJAX :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getDate.php",                 
    dataType:"json",
    data :{
        fromDate:fromDate,
        toDate:toDate
    },
    success: function(data) {
         ......
        }
});
```

This service contains :

```
$fromDate = $_GET['fromDate'];
$toDate = $_GET['toDate'];
$fromDate=date_create($fromDate);
$fromdate = date_format($fromDate,"Y-m-d")."T".date_format($fromDate,"H:i:s")."Z";
$fromdate = urlencode($fromdate);
$toDate=date_create($toDate);
$todate = date_format($toDate,"Y-m-d")."T23:00:00Z";
$todate = urlencode($todate);
$url = "http://194.209.53.19:8086/query?db=Bellevue&q=select+*+from+measures+where+time%3E%3D%27".$fromdate."%27+and+time%3C%3D%27".$todate."%27";
$data = file_get_contents($url, false);
echo $data;
```

I need to use this in my Rails application. I was wondering if I could put the .php file in a Rails folder, and simply call it. Or if there's a way to do a similar service in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do this in Rails. First, you need to define the route for your request. Write the following in your routes.rb file, located at config/routes.rb:

```
get "/getDate" => "generals#get_date"
```

What that means is: whenever there is a `GET` request for `/getDate`, go to controller `GeneralController`, and invoke its function named `get_date`. If you wrote `users#get_date`, Rails would try to find the `get_date` method in `UsersController`.

Generate the controller of your choice by following command:

```
rails generate controller General
```

It will generate a file named general_controller.rb in app/controller among other files.

Now, you need to define all your logic there. Other thing: in PHP, you get the sent data using `$_GET['formDate']`, but in Rails, you will accomplish the same functionality by doing `params[:formDate]`.

```
def get_date
  form_date = params[:formDate]
  # and now here you can write all your logic, and can finally return the response

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: data_to_be_returned } 
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

For `date_create` or `date_format` functions in PHP, you can look up their equivalents at [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) and [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime).

Comment: Thanks for this, look pretty easy to do ! My problem now is that I don't know the Rails equivalent of date_create, date_format, etc. Do you have a link or something that you can provide me with ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you think my answer is valid, and helped you, you can accept it.

Comment: It worked by doing using strftime, thanks. I accepted your answer.